# Just switch from Windows to Ubuntu Linux, my ALT, CTRL, and WINDOWS key acts like the SHIFT key, only uppercasing letters

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Not sure if this is normal with Ubuntu, but the keys that I have said in the title for some reason are acting like the shift key, rather than the keys that they should be acting as when I press another letter to go with it.

For example:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Select all)

Outputs an uppercase "A"

In terminal, I typed "xev", pressed control, I get this as an output.

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
root 0x2cf, subw 0x5200002, time 1751121, (19,67), root:(1207,119),
state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Here is also an output of "xinput"

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Keyboard                              id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ USB Keyboard                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: This is not normal, but without details it is hard to guess what is the problem.

Comment: I added an output of what the key does in xev, not sure if it helps.

Comment: Please also add output of `xinput` command.

Comment: I added the output of xinput

Comment: And what is your real keyboard name? It seems that it is not recognized.

Comment: Redragon S101 VAJRA USB Gaming Keyboard

Comment: It looks like this keyboard is not supported by Linux. You can try to search internet to find a solution for this keyboard in linux, but I doubt it.

Comment: That's odd, I have the box with me and I checked, it says it should be supported on Linux

Comment: Try another keyboard. If it works, then this is a specific keyboard problem.

Comment: Tested on 2 different keyboards, same problem

Comment: Maybe you've set a wrong keyboard layout?

Comment: Shouldn't be, I chose the English (US) keyboard layout